# Getting 403 Forbidden error when trying to load image from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase storage to store and load images for users on my android app. All users must be authenticated before using it. Occasionally, some user profile images are not showing and throwing "403 Forbidden" error. Those images were displaying before, I'm not sure why they stop working.
i'm using the following rules on my firebase storage:

```
 service firebase.storage {
   match /b/<storage_address>.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
     allow read: if request.auth != null;
     allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

if i change the read rule to  `allow read;` all the images are working properly.
This is my display method:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
                builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
                    {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                builder.build().load(URL).into(imgView);
```

The image URL looks something like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<storage_address>.appspot.com/o/images%2Fprofile%2Fphoto%2F36805?alt=media&token=e62ec151-3aaf-4e5c-aefb-1b3c93828684
```

Could it be something to do with the token?

Comment: Do you get the URL passed to `builder.build().load(URL)` using `StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()`?  If so, I don't know how changing the security rules would affect behavior.  Access to the file through this URL is public--not controlled by the rules.

Comment: I suspect the 403 error is not the result of the image download, but something else, such as your call to get the download URL.  Post the code you use to get the URL.

Answer (score 65):

Probably comes too late, but maybe helpful for someone else. I had the same issue, my problem is that filenames in firebase storage are unique. If you upload a new file with the same filename it will override the old one and generate a new token for it, making the old url obsolete.
You should generate a unique filename for your uploaded file and then it should be fixed.

Comment: How did you end up doing this? I'm having the same problem in an IOS project!

Comment: I just appended the current timestamp to the filename.

Comment: In mine I'm using the same name for files. To make it work for me I deleted the current ref and just uploaded with the same exact filename and it seems to work.

Comment: your response has been indeed very, very useful !!!

Comment: Very useful! Solved it for me

Comment: I was doing `getDownloadUrl()` BEFORE uploading the file to storage with `widget.ref.putFile`, and because of that my download URL was returning 403.

Spent hours on this to figure I just had to put it after the upload, since the path already existed in storage and the image was being replaced with each upload.

Answer (score 18):

If you are just testing Storage you might not have implemented Authentication. By default Storage expects uploading user to be authenticated. To by-pass that, in the Storage->Rules write this :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

Worked like a charm for me. Have fun using Firebase

Comment: NOTE: that this should only be for dev mode really, and most would probably recommend some auth to upload files

Answer (score 15):

You get the following error if the extension of your file is either incorrect or missing:

```
 {
    "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
    }
 }
```

In the image URL you provided there is no extension for the image after the image name.

I have tested with one of my urls, this works (you can test):
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/training-a0a3e.appspot.com/o/penguin-56101_640.jpg?alt=media&token=8dfb913d-e2f3-4956-bd3a-2c3746d0d6d3

However when the .jpg is removed:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/training-a0a3e.appspot.com/o/penguin-56101_640?alt=media&token=8dfb913d-e2f3-4956-bd3a-2c3746d0d6d3

The following response is received:

```
 {
    "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
    }
 }
```

Comment: OK, if you can edit the files that works. Seems my problem was some limit with Facebook. I first thought it was this.

Answer (score 8):

Granting read access to everyone got my app displaying images correctly again:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true; 
      allow write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Probably this is not recommended, but solved the problem for the time being

Comment: This was also my issue. Even though I initialized storage in test mode, for some reason my rules were set to only allow read, write if false. Setting them to request.auth!=null worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. This is a late answer but maybe this can help someone.

The problem for me was exactly as [user2555964](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47738367/5856967) described.

I can see that you only provide the url and it is referencing a token. I assume that you don't download the url from a storage path like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) and just keep the reference in the database.

My problem in detail was that upon uploading a picture I saved the url and kept it in the database and then I had a storage trigger that optimized the picture on firebase cloud functions (copy, optimize, and replace original) which changed the token of the picture, making the token on the url worthless when checking for auth on storage rules.

The solution for me was to store the storage path instead and download the current url with the correct token.

Comment: I have this same issue. When a user leaves a comment with a profile pic, then changes it, the pic in the comment won't update and I get that error. Could you pls elaborate how to store the path and so the token will update with the replacement?

Answer (score 0):

To add to these existing responses, there is a use case I unfortunately ran into that isn't covered here. Say you store two urls separated by a special character of your choice, this is what you would do:

```
var url = 'https://myUrl.jpg + https://anootherUrl.jpg' //This is a representation of the response you get from a query

String myUrl = url.toString().replaceAll("+", "").replaceAll("https://anotherUrl", "")//In Dart this is how to edit string objects. Removing unwanted parts by replacing with a blank
```

If the special character you chose is part of the standard url format, you will get an error. Say you used an underscore(_), some url paths contain underscores so by replacing all underscores with a blank, the path becomes invalid thus throwing a 403 Forbidden error. To resolve it, just inspect the format of your urls and pick a separator that is not within it (IF necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to update write permission

Please change the rule in google firebase console : Storage -> rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```