# Images don't get rendered after page refresh (GET 403 Errors) React and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple application where users upload images and see them. After the upload is complete, app routes to /yourlibrary and images are shown. But they are not shown when the page is refreshed. When the user clicks yourlibrary button in the app, the first click doesn't do anything, the second click retrieves some of the images but also many GET 403 permission errors. (If the user has only 3 images these GET 403 errors don't show up.)

The user logged in is true. Sorry if I couldn't structure my question well, but I have no idea why this is happening. I will edit the question once I understand it a little bit better.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from "../firebase/config"
export default class Photos extends Component {
  state={
    photos:[]
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    let images=[]
    firebase.firestore().collection(localStorage.getItem("user_id")).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          let imageData={
            url:doc.data().url,
            created:doc.data().added
          }
          images.push(imageData)

      });
  });
  this.setState({ photos: images });
  }
  render() {
    const items=this.state.photos;

    return (
      <div className="container-fluid pt-3">
        <div className="card-columns">
          {items.map((item)=>(
            <div className="card">
              <img key={item.url} className="card-img-top materialboxed" src={item.url} alt=""/>
            </div>
         ))}
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState({ photos: images });` is placed at wrong place, please check below code snippet

```
componentDidMount(){
    let images=[]
    firebase.firestore().collection(localStorage.getItem("user_id")).get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => { // <--- To get access to this.state
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            let imageData={
                url:doc.data().url,
                created:doc.data().added
            }
            images.push(imageData)
        });
        this.setState({ photos: images }); //<---- it should be here
    });
    // images will not be updated here, due to asynchronous execution
    // this.setState({ photos: images });
}
```

Comment: I did your recommendation but I get the error : 
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: @osmancakirio, i think you didnt copy whole code , this is second change `.then((querySnapshot) => {`

Comment: ah, thank you so much. now it is showing when the first click happens. this nearly saved my day. now first click works but still getting the 403 errors. some images load some don't.

Comment: `403 Forbidden Error` you might need to check access from server

Comment: permissions are set as : rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Comment: It is related to filenames, I guess. I have found some people have similar problems when users upload files with the same name.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943860/getting-403-forbidden-error-when-trying-to-load-image-from-firebase-storage