# can't display image in website when using firebase hosting(403 error)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am making a webpage and have a problem when try to display image from external site.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("width","50%");
img.src = img_url;
```

this work perfectly fine in localhost but get 403 error when using `firebase deploy` and go to website's url.

(can confirm that image url is valid and correct)

Is there anyway to get around this?

this is not duplicated of [Getting 403 Forbidden error when trying to load image from Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943860/getting-403-forbidden-error-when-trying-to-load-image-from-firebase-storage) because I'm trying to get image from external website using firebase hosting, not load image from firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be with the img_url and its path. Can you access this path on another device?

Comment: Yes, I can access that path when directly open with browser, I think it's something to do with firebase config.

Comment: without context, that does not rule it out. you could be using a `file:///path/to/image.jpg` that's why I mentioned on another device rather than another browser. any browser on the same device has access to the same resources.
 so the result is that it's either not deploying to Hosting, or the URL path is external from your app and not resolvable.

Comment: sorry, I mean the image is on another website, not hosting on firebase, so this image can be certainly open on another device.

Comment: are you inserting the image src with `https`? all external connections from hosting must be secured, `http://` is denied